# How to convert local HTML file into String?

Tags: html, string, swift, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I'm working on a simple app as a beginner project which is supposed to send mail with HTML body. **I need to convert HTML file into String.** Then I can put it as html body of mail. Thank you

```
var url_k_html = NSURL(fileURLWithPath:NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("main", ofType:"html")!)
```

UPDATE: I also write **solution** here for clarity because it's in answer's comment:

```
var url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath:NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("file", ofType:"html")!)!
var string = String(contentsOfURL: url, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)!
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
let url = NSURL(yourURLfile)
let yourstring = String(fromUrl: url)
```

Comment: Thanks but doesn't work. Error: " incorrect argument in call ... " expected 'stringInterpolationSegment:' "

Comment: Check the value url for being optional. If it is unwrap it. Do you have output if you try println(url)?

Comment: I unwrapped it. This is not the issue. When I try to print url it looks ok: Optional(file:///Users/Adam/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/D428D91D-0AD2-4773-9ADB-6CC48B6D3E05/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/A4DBE224-1963-4D7E-A340-DA33F8DBE4DB/iOSMail.app/main.html)

Comment: It has to be initiated with String class. Check init methods of String class. You will find the one suitable

Comment: After hours I solved it:
var url = NSURL(url_file)!;
var string = String(contentsOfURL: url, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)!

Thanks for help!

Comment: I already did it. Immediately after my comment ;)